# How to display HTML text in TextView

Tags: html, ios, swift, swift2, uitextview

I have a string containing HTML. I would like to display the HTML in a TextView control. I found some code and tried it:

```
def = "some html text"

definition.attributedText = NSAttributedString(
  data: def.dataUsingEncoding(NSUnicodeStringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)!,
  options: [ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType],
      documentAttributes: nil,
      error: nil)
```

On the option I get an error:

> [String: String] is not convertible to string.

Can someone help me display HTML in a TextView?

Comment: It looks like NSAttributedString is returning a two-dimensional array. I think you're going to have to iterate through the enumeration.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This works for me.  Remember that the `NSAttributedString` constructor now `throws` an `NSError` object:

Swift 3:

```
do {
    let str = try NSAttributedString(data: def.data(using: String.Encoding.unicode, allowLossyConversion: true)!, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute : NSHTMLTextDocumentType], documentAttributes: nil)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Swift 2.x:

```
do {
    let str = try NSAttributedString(data: def.dataUsingEncoding(NSUnicodeStringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)!, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute : NSHTMLTextDocumentType], documentAttributes: nil)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: When I use this code, I get the following message in the console: "+[CATransaction synchronize] called within transaction." Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: @EvanKaminsky Hmm, not sure without more context.  Can you ask a new question showing where you are calling this and what the HTML string is?

Comment: I believe it is the same issue as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28457998/swift-catransaction-synchronize-called-within-transaction-while-decoding-htm, but the current solution uses an external library.

Comment: @EvanKaminsky Interesting, I've never seen that before.  I'll see if I can reproduce the issue and investigate a fix.

Comment: I have a <a href... tag in my html with a url to open, how can can work with it using UITextView or UILabel

Answer (score 0):

Try [SwiftSoup](https://github.com/scinfu/SwiftSoup). This work for me .

```
let html = "<html><head><title>First parse</title></head><body><p>Parsed HTML into a doc.</p></body></html>"
let doc: Document = try SwiftSoup.parse(html)
let text: String = try doc.text()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the **Swift3** version of the code which I found here:

https://github.com/codepath/objc_ios_guides/wiki/Generating-NSAttributedString-from-HTML

```
            func styledHTMLwithHTML(_ HTML: String) -> String {
                let style: String = "<meta charset=\"UTF-8\"><style> body { font-family: 'HelveticaNeue'; font-size: 20px; } b {font-family: 'MarkerFelt-Wide'; }</style>"
                return "\(style)\(HTML)"
            }

            func attributedString(withHTML HTML: String) -> NSAttributedString {
                let options: [AnyHashable: Any] = [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType]
                return try! NSAttributedString(data: HTML.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, options: options as! [String : Any], documentAttributes: nil)
            }

            // This is a string that you might find in your model
            var html: String = "This is <b>bold</b>"

            // Apply some inline CSS
            var styledHtml: String = styledHTMLwithHTML(html)

            // Generate an attributed string from the HTML
            var attributedText: NSAttributedString = attributedString(withHTML: styledHtml)

            // Set the attributedText property of the UILabel
            label.attributedText = attributedText
```